# cross-browser element onresize (HTML / JS)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I know that IE [supports the `onresize` event for any element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while FireFox supports it [for the `window` object only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onresize).

Since I need that functionality for any modern browser I am currently using a (fairly fast) interval timer that continuously checks the `clientWidth`/`clientHeight` of an element to emulate the `onresize`. Of course this is very inefficient and I'd like to know if there is a cross-browser way that does this. Or, alternatively, different methods that work in Firefox/WebKit/IE so that the timer-method can be used as a fallback for remaining browsers.

Targeting at plain JavaScript, instead of jQuery / Prototype etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery then you must check what browser sends to your's script, so:

```
if(!element.onresize != null) element.onresize += event;
if(!element.onresizeAnotherHandler != null) element.onresizeAnotherHandler += event;
```

I don't know is it that easy, but it is a general concept.

EDIT: It looks like there is not event handler for Firefox. But there is an trick:

- If you are changing width in your's JS just create an function update

  ```
  function update(var nx, var ny){
      // do something with nx and ny
  }
  ```
- If you added an resize handle using CSS do it using JavaScript
- If you are using something like 80% in your's CSS then handle window.onresize:

  ```
  function resize(){
      alert(document.getElementById("test").style.width);
  }
  ```

  window.onresize = resize;

It looks that there is no other way.

Comment: What I need is a direct event from the browser when an element changes it's size. AFAIK this is only available in IE...

Comment: It looks like it is impossible for now.